# Force table cell to get the biggest height from the other cells in a row

Tags: html, css, textarea, html-table

This is my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></td>
            <td><textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is visible in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a20skufL/).

Basically, when I resize textarea in one column, i'd like the other textarea to have the same height as the other one (basically force the cell to increase the height).

I'd like to know whether there's a **CSS-only** approach available to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `min-height: 100%;` to `textarea` should make it behave in the way you are after.

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
    border: 3px dashed red;
    padding: 15px;
}

textarea{
    resize: vertical;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></td>
            <td><textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**
Given the problems with the above solution I've come up with another way of handling this making sure that **a)** it works in Firefox (as well as Chrome) and **b)** allows for multiple resizes. This solution does make some major changes:

- An extra `div` around the `table` that handles the resize
- The `textarea`s no longer resize

The reason behind this is that resizing an element sets a `height` on it, so if you resize a `textarea` the containing cell grows to fit it; if you then try and shrink the other `textarea` it doesn't work because the cells have grown to fit the `height` of the larger `textarea`.

```css
div {
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    resize: vertical;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 100%;
}
td {
    border: 3px dashed red;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}
textarea {
    height: 100%;
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/m7t5cqk8/

Comment: Unfortunately I just realised that this only seems to work in Chrome but not Firefox.

Comment: There was a problem with this approach I highlighted as a comment to a previous user that responded in a similar way (i suppose he deleted his post). Basically, if you alternatively increase the textareas' size, then you alternatively reduce them (in a random way, prefferably opposite to the order you increased them), they won't resize anymore

Comment: @Zubzob Interesting, didn't notice that, but I guess it makes sense given that `min-height` will effectively increase every time you make the box bigger. Back to the drawing board I guess!

Comment: @Zubzob Please see my updated answer. I don't know if this is suitable as the resize ability is taken away from the `textarea`s and moved to a wrapper `div` instead.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. While I was more into having a resizer per textarea, this could be a good workaround. Since I don't think it's possible through CSS alone to do what I wanted in my initial question, I'll just mark your solution as the answer. Thanks :)